# Can't Reboot into Windows 8.1 from Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-8, uefi

I am newb in Ubuntu. Currently I am using an Acer V11 laptop with a pre-intalled Windows 8.1. I follow some guideline (http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2014/05/install-ubuntu-1404-alongside-windows.html) which successfully install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS alongside Windows 8.1 with UEFI enabled all the way throughout the installation and my current usage and a GRUB. But I got into some problem.

The dual boot mostly works fine as I am able to successfully boot into either one of the Windows 8.1 or Ubuntu when stating my laptop. However it ran into issue after I start the device and use Ubuntu for a while (2 hour for instance) and then restart it: If I press the restart from Ubuntu, the grub still shows and I am still able to choose the Windows Boot Manager. But the Windows loading process was stuck at the Acer Loading Screen and I am not able to see the standard circular Win8 loading progress bar. Does someone know why would this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm I had some issues with secure boot being on.  However, try removing the option to view boot manager from Windows.  Windows cannot handle more than one boot record on UEFI, no matter what you do.  You can change the boot order via MoBo BIOS by selecting the UEFI option under your boot system menu.  you should see something like an onboard PXE IPv4 and IPv6 NIC Boot and the two OS Options (windows and Ubuntu with numbers on the side in ()s.  Find the command to move Ubuntu up to the first choice.  This is going to always boot to Ubuntu, and having Windows just boot without you choosing an OS will remedy the issue.  Also turn Secure Boot off.

Comment: thanks but I realize Acer V11 disable the options to close secure boot lol

Comment: Actually i found a way to disable it https://acer.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/27072/kw/UEFI/related/1/session/L2F2LzEvdGltZS8xNDA4NjQ3MDIwL3NpZC84QzFzKnAqbA%3D%3D

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you must go to bios option, and configure advance boot option, change boot mode from CSM boot to EUFI boot option, save setting and restart.

Comment: do you mean UEFI boot option? I thought i was always in this option